# read the html file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, file-read

In java i have to read multiple files to search some text . Files are containing large html data so its difficult to read the content of the html file with the help of following code . 
Is any direct method to fetch the content of a file using java . I am using the following code but its making my application slow suggest me the best alternate of it

```
try{
   FileReader fr=new FileReader("path of the html file");
   BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
    String content="";
   while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
    {

     content=content+s;

    } 

     System.out.println("content is"+content);
   }
  catch(Exception ex)
   {

    }
```

Comment: you can use http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @adesh please for why reason is there Swing and AWT tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String concatenation is always slow when done in a loop

You will need to change it to using a StringbBuilder and giving that StringBuilder a decent starting size.

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader("path of the html file");
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder(1024);
while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
    content.append(s);
    }
```

Comment: the default size for the builder. this size is used as starting size for allocation, once your String gets bigger as your starting size then the builder wil double its internal size and to do this it has to create a new internal array. To avoid lots of unneccasery copiing your choose it high enough, 1024 is a guess if you know you will usually read HTML with 1000000 character you can specify it as new StringBuilder(1000000);